# How can I send an xls file one line per time through http response?

Tags: python, excel, http, csv, flask

**Problem**

Recently I got a problem with export large amount of data, and send it to the client side.

The detailed problem description shows in the linked page below:

[How can I adapt my code to make it compatible to Microsoft Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070098/how-can-i-adapt-my-code-to-make-it-compatible-to-microsoft-excel/28076851#28076851)

**What's Different**

Although, the first answer in the linked page help me to solve the problem of messy code when open the ***.csv*** file by excel. But as I commented, it would be a little inconvenient for the user. So I tried to export an ***.xls*** file directly.

**My Question Is**

> Because the dataset is quite large, I cannot generate the whole ***.xls*** file all at once, maybe it's a good idea to send one line or several lines to the client side per time as I did with the ***.csv*** file.
>
> So how can I send the ***.xls*** data piece by piece to the client side? or any better recommendations?

I would be really appreciated for your answer!

Comment: why don't you split the file and send it (s inSplitter or similar), then rejoin it using python or similar , xls cannot be reliably broken into rows due to merged cells etc , it would be alot of work to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution using dependencies flask + sql-alchemy + pandas

```
def export_query(query, file_name = None):

    results = db.session.execute(query)

    fetched = results.fetchall()

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(fetched)

    dataframe.columns = get_query_coloumn_names(query)

    base_path = current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
    workingdocs = base_path + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S") + '/'

    if not os.path.exists(workingdocs):
        os.makedirs(workingdocs)

    if file_name is None:
        file_name = workingdocs + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '-' + 'export.xlsx'
    else:
        file_name = workingdocs + file_name

    dataframe.to_excel(file_name)
    return file_name

def export_all(q, page_limit, page):

    query = db.session.query(...).\
                                outerjoin(..).\
                                filter(..).\
                                order_by(...)
    paging_query = query.paginate(page, page_limit, True)
    # TODO need to return total to help user know to keep trying paging_query.total
    return export_query(paging_query)

@api.route('/export_excel/', methods=['POST'])
@permission_required(Permission.VIEW_REPORT)
def export_excel():
    json = request.get_json(silent=False, force=True)
    q = ''.join(('%',json['q'],'%'))
    page_limit = try_parse_int(json['page_limit'])
    page = try_parse_int(json['page'])

    file_name = export_all(q, page_limit, page)
    response = send_file(file_name)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.xlsx"
    return response
```